# Unit test cosmosDb methods using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, azure-cosmosdb

Since there is no documentation for testing CosmosDb I am trying to do it myself but I have trouble doing it. For example I want to test an insert method that looks like this:

```cs
public async Task AddSignalRConnectionAsync(ConnectionData connection)
{
    if (connection != null)
    {
        await this.container.CreateItemAsync<ConnectionData>(connection, new PartitionKey(connection.ConnectionId));
    }
}
```

What I need to do is test if this method successfully create an item on the cosmosDb or at least fakes an successful creation. **How can I test this?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to unit test that method in isolation, the dependencies of the class under test would need to be mocked.

Assuming an example like the following

```
public class MySubjectClass {
    private readonly Container container;

    public MySubjectClass(Container container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public async Task AddSignalRConnectionAsync(ConnectionData connection) {
        if (connection != null) {
            var partisionKey = new PartitionKey(connection.ConnectionId);
            await this.container.CreateItemAsync<ConnectionData>(connection, partisionKey);
        }
    }        
}
```

In the above example, the method under test is dependent on `Container` and `ConnectionData`, which need to be provided when testing.

Unless you want to hit an actual instance of the `Container` it would be recommended to mock dependencies that can have undesirable behavior if an actual implementation is used.

```
public async Task Should_CreateItemAsync_When_ConnectionData_NotNull() {
    //Arrange
    //to be returned by the called mock
    var responseMock = new Mock<ItemResponse<ConnectionData>>();

    //data to be passed to the method under test
    ConnectionData data = new ConnectionData {
        ConnectionId = "some value here"
    };

    var containerMock = new Mock<Container>();
    //set the mock expected behavior
    containerMock
        .Setup(_ => _.CreateItemAsync<ConnectionData>(
            data, 
            It.IsAny<PartitionKey>(), 
            It.IsAny<ItemRequestOptions>(),
            It.IsAny<CancellationToken())
        )
        .ReturnsAsync(responseMock.Object)
        .Verifiable();

    var subject = new MySubjectClass(containerMock.Object);

    //Act
    await subject.AddSignalRConnectionAsync(data);

    //Assert
    containerMock.Verify(); //verify expected behavior
}
```

The subject method under test can be verified that it will call the expected method when the parameter is not null based on the above isolated unit test example.

Using a real `Container` would make this an integration test, which would require a different kind of test arrangement.

You could also check how the developers unit test the SDK here

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/tree/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/tests/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Tests

*Credit: [@MatiasQuaranta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5641598/matias-quaranta)*