# Adding Document data in Cosmos db gives error as resource already exist

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have below unit test case where I am trying to add a list of `JObjects` one by one in cosmos Db, but it fails giving an error as

> Resource with specified id or name already exists

while my Db actually is empty and there is no value in there. What wrong am I doing here??

```
[Fact]
public async Task AddDataInCosmosDbEmulator() 
{
  await ReadConfigAsync();

  var jsonData = await ReadAllData();
  Uri collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, RecordingCollection);

  foreach(var obj in jsonData) 
  {
    Document doc = await client.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionUri, obj);
  }
}

private async Task ReadConfigAsync() 
{
  client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(CosmosEndpoint), EmulatorKey,
    new ConnectionPolicy {
      ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
        ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp

    });
}
```

jsonData is of this format:

```
{{"id":"Test1","Name":"123"}},
{{"id":"Test3","Name":"12r3"}},
{{"id":"Test15","Name":"12we3"}},
{{"id":"Test12","Name":"oi123"}}
```

Comment: sorry it is in double quotes. corrected it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some considerations and a suggestion. To make sure that it is something other than the entry really existing, re-write

```
Document doc = await client.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionUri, obj );
```

To

```
Document doc = await client.UpsertDocumentAsync(collectionUri, obj );
```

If this works, then it might be that your local emulator has already got the data. The thing is, that the second time you re-run the unit tests this will be a problem when you actually do an insert.

Check mocking frameworks. Unit tests should only test the code at hand, not actual persistence items and such?

How would you solve this problem on a build server? How would you pipeline this? Leave actual integration testing for integration tests. Check [Unit test cosmosDb methods using Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58768313/unit-test-cosmosdb-methods-using-moq)

Comment: Thanks, Upsert thing worked. and you points are valid. The way I wanted to go is to have a method having Mockdata inserted and this method is being called by each of my test case.